# Where can I find a good C# console app that demonstrates polling?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, polling

I'm looking for a good example of polling in C#.

Basically, every X seconds an instrument is read and the values logged to a text file. I was looking for a sample that makes use of .NET 4's parallel library. Or, maybe I'm overthinking this solution by looking at TPL...

ps- this question is unrelated to my previous question about database polling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd particularly bother with TPL here. Just use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) to perform an action periodically. Those will both use the thread pool - what are you planning on doing in the main console thread during this time?

Of course, another *extremely* simple option would be to just make the main thread sleep between poll occurrences. It's crude, but if that's *all* your app needs to do, it may well be good enough for you. I'm not sure how it behaves if the system clock is changed, mind you... is this for a very long-running task for production usage, or just a quick tool? (If it's a long-running app, you might want to consider using a Windows Service instead.)

Comment: This will be for long-running production use and I was considering a windows service. We're prototyping something right now to see how all the pieces fit together. This component will likely end up being a service unless we find a compelling reason to leave it as a console app.

Comment: @SpecialAgent_W436: In that case I'd probably go for one of the timer classes. Both are pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

It's real easy to create a timer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a timer that polls once every 5 seconds
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerProc, null, 5000, 5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Polling every 5 seconds.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter when done:");
    Console.ReadLine();
    timer.Dispose();
}

static int TickCount = 0;
static void TimerProc(object state)
{
    ++TickCount;
    Console.WriteLine("tick {0}", TickCount);
}
```

Note that the `TimerProc` is called on a separate thread. Your main program can do other things, and this will continue to poll every five seconds until you kill (or modify) the timer.

I prefer `System.Threading.Timer` over `System.Timers.Timer` because the latter swallows exceptions. If there is a bug in your elapsed event handler that throws an exception, you'll never know about it because the `System.Timers.Timer` event handler will suppress the exception. For that reason, I strongly suggest that you not use it. Use `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PL doesn't sound correct to me for this task.  I recommend checking out [System.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) with which you can specify a recurring interval at which the Elapsed event is raised in your application allowing you to handle the event to perform regular processing.